# Read single values from JSON file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file data.json as below

```
{
    "data": {
        "d1": ["data1", "data2"],
        "d2": [{
            "id": "3456",
            "name": "dummy"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to read values in `d1` key. How i can do that?

Comment: `$.getJSON('data.json',function(data){ console.log(data.data.d1); })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jquery ajax get function

```
$.get('/data.json',function(data){ 
  console.log(data.data.d1[0]);
})
```

Comment: Better to ue `$.getJSON` to ensure that it's treated as JSON.